# Using Jquery, replace one row in table with a new one

Tags: jquery, html-table

Say I have a table:

```
<table id="mytable">
      <tr class="old_row"><td>1</td><td>2</td><td class="edit">Edit</td></tr>
      <tr class="old_row"><td>1</td><td>2</td><td class="edit">Edit</td></tr>
      <tr class="old_row"><td>1</td><td>2</td><td class="edit">Edit</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to click on the `<td>Edit</td>` cell and use jquery to replace the entire row with a new row with more content, e.g.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#mytable .edit').click( function() {

            var tr = $(this).parent();
            var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Save</td></tr>'
            // code to replace this row with the new_row
        });

    } );
```

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mytable .edit').click( function() {

        var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Save</td></tr>'
        $(this).parent().replaceWith(new_row);
    });

} );
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [jQuery.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytable .edit').click( function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Save</td></tr>';
    tr.replaceWith(new_row);
  });
});
```

Comment: @Samich ... The same thing I posted only your create new_row as a jQuery object whereas I left it as an HTML String.  Essentially the same code.

Comment: Yep. :) But you are typing faster than me.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `replaceWith()`.  Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable .edit').click( function() {

        var tr = $(this).parent();
        var new_row = '<tr class="new_row"><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Save</td></tr>'
        tr.replaceWith(new_row); // code to replace this row with the new_row
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hAvyv/

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('old_row').addClass('new_row').html('<td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Save</td>');
});
```