# How can I use a JSON response in conditional python logic?

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I'm using ajax to asynchronously update a boolean variable in my Django project. I'm able to successfully display this variable using the template but I'm not sure how I can use this variable in the template's embedded python logic.

Basically

```
{% if JSON_BOOL %}

<p>this</p>

{% else %}

<p>that</p>

{% endif %}
```

Where the `JSON_BOOL` is being supplied by an ajax function.  What's the best way to make the variable available to the conditional logic? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838975/how-to-get-values-from-the-ajax-into-django-template

Comment: Pretty similar to what I'm asking, @Arpan, but that answer doesn't specify how I can use the returned JSON as a python variable. Thanks!

Comment: Just so I understand your problem, you need to transform a JSON variable being rendered in a template from text to a bool value so you can use it in the conditional logic?

Comment: @JwM that's my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this. If I were you, I would just leave the variable in text format and in your code say:

```
{% if JSON_BOOL == "True" %}
...
{% else %}
...the rest of your code
```

Otherwise you could cast it to a boolean on the python side of things. This would look as follows in your view:

```
if JSON_BOOL == "True":
    JSON_BOOL = True
else:
    JSON_BOOL = False
```

I'm not aware of a way to cast variables to different types within the template itself..this seems to be outside of its scope of functionality, and either way it's better to keep functionality out of templates. Hope this helps.